# C++ mathematical function generation

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

In working on a project I came across the need to generate various waves, accurately.  I thought that a simple sine wave would be the easiest to begin with, but it appears that I am mistaken.  I made a simple program that generates a `vector` of samples and then plays those samples back so that the user hears the wave, as a test.  Here is the relevant code:

```
vector<short> genSineWaveSample(int nsamples, float freq, float amp) {
  vector<short> samples;
  for(float i = 0; i <= nsamples; i++) {
    samples.push_back(amp * sinx15(freq*i));
  }
  return samples;
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue with this is.  I understand that there could be some issue with the vector being made of `short`s, but that's what my audio framework wants, and I am inexperienced with that kind of library and so do not know what to expect.

The symptoms are as follows:

- frequency not correct

  - ie: given freq=440, A4 is not the note played back
- strange distortion

  - Most frequencies do not generate a clean wave. 220, 440, 880 are all clean, most others are distorted
- Most frequencies are shifted upwards considerably

Can anyone give advice as to what I may be doing wrong?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Making my own sine function, for greater accuracy.

  - I used a 15th degree Taylor Series expansion for sin(x)
- Changed the sample rate, anything from 256 to 44100, no change can be heard given the above errors, the waves are simply more distorted.

Thank you.  If there is any information that can help you, I'd be obliged to provide it.

Comment: better change `i` to type `int`, most probably it will not fix anything, but will work faster

Comment: What does `sinx15` do?

Comment: @EdHeal, I should have mentioned that, `sinx15` is my 15th degree Taylor polynomial sine approximation.

Comment: What is the frequency parameter? You're going to need at least two samples per cycle to get unaliased waves. You might be forgetting a 2pi term. Is "frequency" passed as omega (2*pi*frequency) or just plain frequency? Also the way you have it implemented you're going to want i / frequency or something of the sort.

Comment: @Slava, will do.  I thought there might end up being a typecasting issue

Comment: @Apcragg The frequency parameter is just a number, so for example, if I give it 1000, it should be 1000Hz.  I'll try it with the omega argument as you specified.

Comment: See my answer, you need to take the frequency parameter as well as your playback sample frequency and evaluate it as a ration THEN multiply it by 2pi * i

Comment: What is sinx15(22) or sinx15(355)? That is, before Tayloring, do you reduce the argument by multiples of 2pi?

Comment: @LutzL yup, it takes care of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are passing incorrect values to your *sin15x* function. If you are familiar with the basics of signal processing the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) is the minimum frequency at which you can faithful reconstruct (or in your case construct) a sampled signal. The is defined as 2x the highest frequency component present in the signal.

What this means for your program is that you need at last 2 values per cycle of the highest frequency you want to reproduce. At 20Khz you'd need 40,000 samples per second. It looks like you are just packing a vector with values and letting the playback program sort out the timing.

We will assume you use 44.1Khz as your playback sampling frequency. This means that a snipet of code producing one second of a 1kHz wave would look like

```
DataStructure wave = new DataStructure(44100) // creates some data structure of 44100 in length

for(int i = 0; i < 44100; i++)
{
  wave[i] = sin(2*pi * i * (frequency / 44100) + pi / 2) // sin is in radians, frequency in Hz
}
```

You need to divide by the frequency, not multiply. To see this, take the case of a 22,050 Hz frequency value is passed. For i = 0, you get sin(0) = 1. For i = 1, sin(3pi/2) = -1 and so on are so forth. This gives you a repeating sequence of 1, -1, 1, -1... which is the correct representation of a 22,050Hz wave sampled at 44.1Khz. This works as you go down in frequency but you get more and more samples per cycle. Interestingly though this does not make a difference. A sinewave sampled at 2 samples per cycle is just as accurately recreated as one that is sampled 1000 times per second. This doesn't take into account noise but for most purposes works well enough.

I would suggest looking into the basics of digital signal processing as it a very interesting field and very useful to understand.

Edit: This assumes all of those parameters are evaluated as floating point numbers.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  This is not at all how I thought about this in the first place, but I think the key here has been dividing by the sample rate.  I will have to research this, and I see where the frequency multiplication could be a problem based on the Nyquist frequency issue that you mentioned.  I'm not sure how this works mathematically yet, but I'll certainly look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah the sample rate bit is important. I suspect the reason you were getting some results with 220, 440, etc was that they were being aliased to hell and you got lucky that those aliases fell in the audible range albeit heavily distorted

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you're missing a piece of information.  You don't specify the amount of time over which you want your samples taken.  This could also be thought of as the rate at which the samples will be played by your system.  Something roughly in this direction will get you closer, for now, though.

```
samples.push_back(amp * std::sin(M_PI / freq *i));
```

Comment: This generates an extremely long wavelength, and is inaudible when played back.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what the data in the vector should look like.  I'm assuming that, if you graphed them, they should fall along a sine wave with the given frequency?  I'm no audio engineer, but I can help you with the code if I can understand what resulting data you want.

Comment: that's correct, it should look like a sine wave, and I wrote a simple program to generate a CSV for a given frequency, and graphed it in a spreadsheet, and it does look like a sine wave as I wrote it.  The `nsamples` parameter defines how many points to generate.  The function generates the wave in terms of samples, not in terms of time, and the samples correlate to time when played back, but the generator function is unaware of how much time will pass.

Comment: I would still need to know the play back rate.  It's impossible to achieve a specific frequency output if you don't know the frequency with which the samples will be played back at.  The issue is, essentially, one of scaling along the time axis.  Your code posted here certainly generates a sine pattern, but the frequency will vary inversely to the input frequency.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have some research to do... Perhaps I do not understand this as well as I think I do.